# How reader quotas in wcf bindings works?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I tried to set maxarraylength value to 5 but it does not seems to be working. From where I can get detail of this.

Is reader quotas only work server side or is it required for client configuration as well?

Comment: It is very common question. Just search it out, You will get an answer.

Comment: It is common but it is not work as expected.i have set value 5 so it should restrict to 5 but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

maxArrayLength configuration is required for client too

> These attributes must be set on the client and service. Once set in
>   the service’s configuration file, these values will not be propagated
>   automatically to the client’s configuration file that is generated by
>   the svcutil tool or Add Service Reference in Visual Studio. You must
>   manually edit the generated client side configuration file and set the
>   appropriate values.

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325(v=vs.110).aspx